# Dual GTX with ATI GPU works slow

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, amd-graphics

I wanted to install a second monitor. Since I don't have an integrated GPU, I found an old ATI Radeon HD 4600 Series and installed it beside my GTX 1050ti.

At first, drivers didn't work so I switched from my nvidia proprietary drivers to xorg open source drivers (after I read that they came with AMD drivers by default). Now the second monitor works too, but everything in it is very slow (browser, filemanager, anything). When I move the apps back on main screen they work normally. How can I fix this?

Here's my inxi -G

```
Graphics:  Card-1: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] RV730 PRO [Radeon HD 4650]
       Card-2: NVIDIA GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti]
       Display Server: X.Org 1.18.4 drivers: ati,radeon (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) FAILED: nouveau
       Resolution: 1920x1080@74.97hz, 1440x900@59.89hz
       GLX Renderer: NV137 GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 17.2.8
```